# How to do INNER JOIN in typeorm (postgresql)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, inner-join, typeorm

I have this two entities:

```js
@Entity()
export class Member {
    @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'room_id' })
    roomId: number;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    email: string;

    @Column({ name: 'is_room_owner' })
    isRoomOwner: boolean;

    @Column('timestamp without time zone', { name: 'joined_at', nullable: true })
    joinedAt: Date | null;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @ManyToOne(() => Room, room => room.members)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'room_id' })
    room: Room;
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Room {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'room_id' })
    roomId: number;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @Column()
    permanent!: boolean;

    @Column()
    active!: boolean;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
    updatedAt: Date;

    @OneToMany(() => Member, member => member.room, { cascade: true })
    members: Member[];
}
```

I would like to get the rooms by the member's email and filter if they are active.
Basically in sql it would be something like this:

```sql
select "room".*, "member".* from room "room"
inner join member "member" on "member".roomId = "room".roomId
where "room".active = :active and "member".email = :email;
```

It should include the members.

I am getting used to typeorm so thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Do you want to use query builder for generating query or you prefer to use standard CRUD API?

Comment: I don't know.. what would be the best approach? From what I've seen in documentation, probaly I would use QueryBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query can be constructed using query builder as follows -

```
  async getRoomsByMember(active: boolean, email: string): Promise<any[]> {
      return await getRepository(Room)
      .createQueryBuilder('room')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('room.member', 'member')
      .where("room.active = :active", {active: active})
      .andWhere("member.email = :email", { email: email })
      .getMany();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just had to change from "room.email" to "member.email".

Comment: My pleasure, made the change as requested!